# Many times in the log I get the same error - processAudioBuffer(34): obtainBuffer(192) returned 192 = 128 + 64 err 0

Tags: android, audio, media-player, ads, audiobuffer

```
V/AudioTrack: processAudioBuffer(34): obtainBuffer(192) returned 192 = 64 + 128 err 0
V/AudioTrack: start(34): prior state:STATE_ACTIVE
V/AudioTrack: processAudioBuffer(34): obtainBuffer(128) returned 128 = 128 + 0 err 0
V/AudioTrack: processAudioBuffer(34): obtainBuffer(192) returned 192 = 192 + 0 err 0
V/AudioTrack: start(34): prior state:STATE_ACTIVE
V/AudioTrack: processAudioBuffer(34): obtainBuffer(192) returned 192 = 192 + 0 err 0
V/AudioTrack: start(34): prior state:STATE_ACTIVE
V/AudioTrack: processAudioBuffer(34): obtainBuffer(192) returned 192 = 192 + 0 err 0
```